# SPDiagnosticsService not working form sharepoint Web Application

Tags: logging, sharepoint-2010

SPDiagnosticsService not working form sharepoint Web Application. After I call the following code I don't any message in ULS log.

```
SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(10001, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("Test", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.High, "Test Mesage", null);
```

However when I call the same code from a Console Application, it is able to write logs and I can see the messages in ULS log.

How can I make it work from a Web Application?

Answer (score 7):

In order to make ULS logging work for a AppPool account that is not Administrator you have to add your AppPool user to "Performance Log Users" group.

And restart the Application Pool that is using this AppPool account.